# How to share variable between two classes without using global variable in Java?

Tags: java, oop, variables

Assume that i have two object `Light` and `LightSwitch` what i want to do is

> Switch on the `LightSwitch` then check that `Light` is turn on or turn off (In this case expected answer is 'on')

*note that when switch is turned on the shared variable name `current` will set to `true` then `Light` will also turn on*

What i am interested in on this problem are:

- How two classes (in this case are class `Light` and `LightSwitch`) can share variable value without using global variable (In this case the shared variable is `current`)?
- How to implements this simple problem in object-oriented concept?

expected output (or just another output you prefer that can tell me ok, light is turn on/off):

```
switch on: true       // This line just set variable `current` in `LightSwitch` class
Light is turned on    // This line just check that `current` variable in `Light` class is True or false 
switch on: false
Light is turned off
```

Comment: Sounds like classic observer design pattern can fit here.

Comment: What do you mean "Global variable"? You mean static variables?

Comment: @LocHa yes, something like `public static ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to this.

**The more specific approach**

```
public class Light implements Switchable{
   private boolean on;

   @Override
   public boolean isOn() { return on; }

   @Override
   public void setIsOn(boolean on) { this.on = on; }       
}


public class LightSwitch {

    public void List<Switchable> switchables = new ArrayList<Switchable>(); // A generic list of things that are controlled by the switch. Doesn't have to be lights.

    public void off() { setState(false); }

    public void on() { setState(true); }

    private void setState(boolean state) {
       for(Switchable switchable: switchables) {
           switchable.setIsOn(state);
       }
    }
}
```

**The observer approach**

The [observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) might be a very good fit for something more generic and it actually extends the example I gave before. If you're not familiar with it, it's a way to implement event and thus tie up between the state of 2 objects while when one is changed the other one "observes" this changes and reacts accordingly. In this case your light observes the switch.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, though in general, this elegant solution is not to use global variables at all, not secretly use them :)

**Singleton Pattern**

Make singleton LightState or whatever - make it's constructor private in a factory class that returns the single, static lightstate when requested. Then, whenever anyone requests the "lightstate", they'll be given the same value

**Static Variables**

Just make a static (private, with getter) variable in one of the two classes and have the other one request it.

**Observer Pattern**

Apply one of the other two methods, but leave the burden on the state to notify the correct agent when the state changes; this way, the agents are not responsible for linking to the state, which keeps linkages simpler and more elegant.

Alternatively, the observer could notify a controller agent, that would then act accordingly with whatever actions need to occur, meaning that the two independent elements can remain completely unaware of the shared information.

**Inheritance**

Is Light a subclass of lightswitch or visa versa? It's usage dependent, but probably not. If so, however, you could make a protected static variables that they can both access. By making a "final" wrapper object for this state, you'd ensure nobobdy every switches it out leading to confusing mis-referencing

**Direct Linkage**

Have the lightswitch track a light. You'll still want to know when the state of the light changes from some means other than the switch, so the observer pattern could still come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, every `LightSwitch` is connected to one (or more) `Light`(s). I would start by passing the `Light` instance to `LightSwitch` (and keep it as a field in in the switch).

```
private Light current;
public LightSwitch(Light light) {
  this.current = light;
  on();
}
public boolean isOn() {
  return current.isOn();
}
public void on() {
  current.setOn(true);
}
public void off() {
  current.setOn(false);
}
public String toString() {
  return isOn() ? "switched on" : "switched off";
}
```

then your `main()` might look like,

```
LightSwitch switch = new LightSwtich(new Light());
System.out.println("Light is: %s%n", switch);
switch.off();
System.out.println("Light is: %s%n", switch);
```

Output would be

```
Light is: switched on
Light is: switched off
```

Answer (score 2):

**Checkout my solution If you want de-couple between LightSwitch & Light. You can easily add/remove the link between lights and switch**

**Light class:**

```
public class Light {

    private boolean on;

    public void setOn(boolean on) {
        this.on = on;
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        return on;
    }
}
```

**LightSwitch class:**

```
public class LightSwitch {

    private boolean on;

    private Map<String, SwitchListener> listeners = new HashMap<String, SwitchListener>();

    public void switchState() {
        on = !on;
        SwitchEvent event = new SwitchEvent(on);

        for (SwitchListener switchListener : listeners.values()) {
            switchListener.switchPerformed(event);
        }
    }

    public void addListener(String id, SwitchListener listener) {
        listeners.put(id, listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(String id) {
        listeners.remove(id);
    }
}
```

**SwitchEvent class:**

```
public class SwitchEvent {

    private boolean on;

    public SwitchEvent(boolean on) {
        this.on = on;
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        return on;
    }
}
```

**SwitchListener class:**

```
public interface SwitchListener {

    void switchPerformed(SwitchEvent event);
}
```

**USING example:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LightSwitch lightSwitch = new LightSwitch();

        final Light light1 = new Light();
        final Light light2 = new Light();

        lightSwitch.addListener("light1", new SwitchListener() {

            @Override
            public void switchPerformed(SwitchEvent event) {
                light1.setOn(event.isOn());
            }
        });

        lightSwitch.addListener("light2", new SwitchListener() {

            @Override
            public void switchPerformed(SwitchEvent event) {

                // Example: light 1 on, light 2 off -- light 1 off, light 2 on
                light2.setOn(!event.isOn());
            }
        });

        // Test switch
        lightSwitch.switchState(); // light 1 ON, light 2 OFF

        lightSwitch.switchState(); // light 1 OFF, light 2 ON
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that in OOP you don't share variables like this.  One of the main points of OOP (as well as other modular programming paradigms) is *encapsulation*.  An object can be modified or queried according to how its public interface specifies that it can.  To modify the object's state or change its behavior, you have to call one of the methods belonging to that object.  That way, the object is in full control of its own state; it knows when its own methods are called, and those methods alone are able to modify the object's state information.

Having a shared variable would ruin all that.  If a variable were shared between two objects, then when one object assigns to the variable, it could modify the behavior of the other object in a way that the other object can't control.  So this is something to be avoided.

Instead, one of the objects will need to call a method of the other object.  Most likely, if you have a `turnOn` method of your `LightSwitch`, it will need to turn on the `Light`.  The most straightforward way to do this, I think, is to tell the `LightSwitch` in its constructor what `Light` it will turn on:

```
public LightSwitch (Light light) { ... }
```

or, if it controls more than one light,

```
public LightSwitch(Light[] light) { ... } // or use a List or Set or whatever
```

Then the constructor will save this reference, and its `turnOn` method will then call `light.turnOn()`.  That's how you would handle this in OOP, not with a shared variable.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is teaching you is giving you some bad habits that will make Java programming (and OOP generally) hard for you.

You need better encapsulation. Something along the lines of

```
class Light {
    ...
    public void startCurrent(){...};
    public void stopCurrent(){...};
    public boolean isOn();
}

class Switch {
    Ligh target;
    public Switch(Ligh target) {...}

    public clickOn(){target.startCurrent();}
    public clickOff(){target.stopCurrent();}
}

// now wire it all together

public static void main(String argv) {
    Light light = new Light();
    Switch switch = new Switch(light);

    System.out.println("Light is on: " + light.isOn());
    switch.clickOn();
    System.out.println("Light is on: " + light.isOn());
    switch.clickOff();
    System.out.println("Light is on: " + light.isOn());
}
```

This is more object-oriented, no need to have any global variables.

Comment: @Arkadity Thank you for your answer what you do i've learnt in OOP class also but i just think that how can light living in switch that make no sense. This case study i just focus on two classes that completely independent but they can share variable to each other. the question is how?

Comment: @terces907: My solution will solve your problem: Completely independent between lights and switch.

Comment: Light does not "live in" Switch. Switch is "aware of" Light. Switch has to switch something, right? (actually, you want a Switchable inteface there). The terms are "composition" (not what we have here) and "directed association" (what we do have here).

Comment: Let discuss about real world. When Switch created, does this switch need to know exactly Light (target)? The answer is NO. SO public Switch(Ligh target) is not great design. Of course it works.

Comment: If you need to make it more realistic, introduce Switchable, CurrentCarrier and Wire.